# Repeated values VS document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

On the same page, I'm using Play repeated values and a `document.querySelector`.

To give a minimal example:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.MyController.myAction()) {
  <input type="search" id="input[0]" />
  <input type="search" id="input[1]" />
  <input type="search" id="input[2]" />
}

<script language="JavaScript">
  var input = document.querySelector('#input[1]');
  something(input);
</script>
```

The issue is that Play uses that format `input[i]` to map repeated fields but the JavaScript engine does not accept it:

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Is there a simple workaround on one side or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CSS selector, square brackets are used to select an attribute. If you want to match it literally, you have to escape them.

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input\\[1\\]');
```

You could also use `getElementById`, which doesn't parse the ID.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input[1]');
```

Comment: I have to admit I feel a bit dummy. It works now. Thanks :)